# Making a struct whose property's type is a struct that has a property of the first struct type

Tags: c++, oop, variables, struct

Suppose we have the following struct:

```
struct Variable {
    Number number;
    String string;
    List list;
    float value;
    std::string type;
    Variable(Number number_); // for int / float values
    Variable(String string_);
    Variable(List list_);
};
```

This is a struct Variable that can be either a number, a string or a list. I did not make these as separate child classes using polymorphism because I need to be able to pass a single Variable struct / return it into/from other functions without knowing whether it is string, number or list (if that makes sense).

However, while the Number struct has a float property and the String struct has a std::string property, the List struct is as follows:

```
struct List {
    std::vector<Variable> values;
    List(std::vector<Variable> Values);
};
```

The problem is obvious: If I declare List before Variable, then its Variable vector property is undefined, and if I declare Variable before List its List property will also be undefined.

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: You can forward declare `Variable` before the definition of `List`. From C++17, `std::vector` will accept incomplete types.

Comment: @cigien Thank you! I had already tried that and it didn't work, but it was because I was using c++11. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Perhaps use `std::variant<Number, String, List>`.

Comment: In addition, "I need to be able to pass a single Variable struct / return it into/from other functions" is probably an imaginary requirement. You can pass/return a *pointer* to a base class. That's how polymorphism works in C++.